# How can I remove the last checkbox from an array using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, checkbox

This is an email preferences form with a bunch of checkboxes (16) to allow users to subscribe/unsubscribe.
I have a collection of checkboxes like this;

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

I have a **button** which when clicked will select all checkboxes on the page and then deselect the unsubscribeAll checkbox;

```
getAllButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectAll();
});

function selectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") checkboxes[i].checked = true;
    }

    // un-check the unsubscribeAll checkbox
    unsubscribeAll.checked = false;
}
```

I have a **checkbox** which when clicked(checked) will deselect all of the other checkboxes on the page;

```
var unsubscribeAll = document.getElementById("unsubscribeAll");

unsubscribeAll.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // un-check this box if already checked
    if (this.checked !== true) {
        this.checked = false;
    } else {
        deselectAll();
    }
});

function deselectAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
    unsubscribeAll.checked = true;
}
```

This is all working perfectly. However, my problem is that if the the unsubscribeAll checkbox is checked and the user then selects a checkbox to subscribe to an email I want to deselect the unsubscribeAll checkbox but I'm struggling to make that happen.
I thought I would be able to run another function that would deselect that checkbox like this;

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", deselectUnsubscribeAll);
}

function deselectUnsubscribeAll() {
    if (unsubscribeAll.checked === true) {
        unsubscribeAll.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because `unsubscribeAll` is included in the `checkboxes[]` array.
Next, I thought I would be able to create a new array of checkboxes that excluded `unsubscribeAll` so I tried this because it's the last element in that array;

```
var unsubscribeAll = document.getElementById("unsubscribeAll");
var getAllButton = document.getElementById("select-all");
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
console.log(checkboxes.length); // 16
var popped = checkboxes.pop(); // Uncaught TypeError: checkboxes.pop is not a function
```

As you can see, that generates an error but I don't understand why. This seems like clunky code but it almost works.
This is one of the pages that I referenced to solve my problem;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop#examples
I need some direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it's the last element in that array, so why do you loop through the end of array and not using `for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length - 1; i++)`?
And then you can add an  event listener separately to that.
You can also use [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) API to check if the clicked checkbox is `unsubscribeAll` and run appropriate functions accordingly. But the first method is more efficient cause you don't need to check for the element on each click event.

Comment: your solution, `checkboxes.length - 1` works nicely and is beautiful in it's simplicity but it doesn't answer the question of why .pop() threw an error in my use case. However, because your answer does effectively remove the unsubscribe checkbox from receiving the `eventListener` and achieves my goal I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Fettabachi Oh, sorry, I forgot to answer that. `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList which doesn't have a `pop()` method. You can learn more here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList